# Evernote Open in App

Tags: evernote

I'm developing an application that lets users view their notes and would like to offer a link to open up a specific note for editing in the Evernote (Windows) app.  In the [glossary](http://dev.evernote.com/support/glossary.php) under Evernote URLs, I see what I think I need but I can't find any documentation on how to use it.

What is the scheme? `evernote://notebook_guid/note_guid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme for note links is documented [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/note_links.php).